# Error while setting MONGODB path on windows 7

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm, database

I am new into mongo db.
I am trying to run `mongod` in the folder 
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`
but it keeps on giving an error.
Here is a screenshot of the error[image]

`\data\db` folder is already created in the c drive.
`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin` is already added in the
`environment variable` named `path`.
Please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, with params `--dbpath ./data/db`, it work well in my local pc.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin>mongod --dbpath ./data/db
```

`dbpath` is one parameter of `mongod` command, here is the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--dbpath),

> `--dbpath <path>`
>   Default: `/data/db` on Linux and OS X, `\data\db` on Windows.
>   The directory where the mongod instance stores its data.
>
> If you installed MongoDB using a package management system, check the `/etc/mongod.conf` file provided by your packages to see the directory is specified.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Can you please write the exact command that you mean?